# using of the gRPC OnCancel method in Callback API for server reactors

Tags: c++, grpc

We are using the examples given by gRPC team here https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/master/examples/cpp/route_guide/route_guide_callback_server.cc

There are several types of stream reactors: ServerWriteReactor, ServerReadReactor, ServerBidiReactor.

There is a code in those examples, that teaches us: when connection is closed by intention on *server* side, the OnDone() callback is triggered. The inherited class deletes its instance this way:

```
   class Lister : public grpc::ServerWriteReactor<Feature> 
   {
   public: 
    ...
    void OnDone() override { delete this; }
    ....
   }
```

But there is one more virtual "callback" function in a base classes - f.e. ServerWriteReactor::OnCancel(), that always triggers when the gGRPC *client* drops the connection from its side.

The problem is, there is no any example given in the gRPC/Example/cpp to show how this function is to be used correctly if overriden by the user's class.
If we place there the same (delete this) code, the later call of grpc::Server::ShutDown() will never return if you want to close the connection form server side. Sometimes, if the data stream used intensively, we get the gRPC internal exception very soon. So, it is not safe to place the same code (delete this) into the OnCancel() function...

So the questions are,

1. how to handle correctly the OnCancel() in stream type server reactors?
2. At which point it is safe to delete the instance of the server reactor after we got OnCancel() triggered?

Comment: Nobody posted any comment in the last 4 days since the question publication. What I did to solve the problem: 1) when get OnCancel(), I post an async event to the owner of the WriteReactor instance. 2) as soon the owner receives this event, it places a data to the WriteReactor. This forces the OnDone to be triggered, and the instance deleted by the same code as above. Works fine.